# Solving a question about Fibonacci and Lucas numbers using induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Im working on practice problems that the instructor gave us yesterday, and I absolutely have no clue of how to solve this problem..
I need to use mathmatical induction to solve this problem..

The question is:

Fibonacci numbers F1, F2, F3, . . . are defined by the rule: F1 = F2 = 1 and Fk = Fk−2 + Fk−1 for k > 2.

Lucas numbers L1, L2, L3, . . . are defined in a similar way by the rule: L1 = 1, L2 = 3 and Lk = Lk−2 + Lk−1 for k > 2.

Show that Fibonacci and Lucas numbers satisfy the following equality for all n ≥ 2

Ln = Fn−1 + Fn+1.

how should I solve this problem using mathematical induction? I found a similar question to this but it was solved by using other method... I need to solve this using induction..

Detailed explanation will be very much appreciated..

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995453/show-that-fibonacci-and-lucas-numbers-satisfy-the-following-equality-for-all-n-%E2%89%A5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you can show it is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$, or for $n=2$ and $n=3$, by looking at actual values.

Then if it is true for $n=k$ and $n=k-1$ then $L_k=F_{k+1}+F_{k-1}$ and $L_{k-1}=F_{k}+F_{k-2}$ so $L_k+L_{k-1}=F_{k+1}+F_{k}+F_{k-1}+F_{k-2}$.

This means $L_{k+1}=F_{k+2}+F_{k}$, i.e.  $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$ for $k=n+1$. And so you can use induction to claim it is true for all integer $n \ge 2$.

Comment: how do you show that for n=2 and n=3 ?I assume that for example when n=2, I should plug in 2 to the equation  Ln = Fn−1 + Fn+1, and get L(2)=f(2-1)+f(2+1) and get F0 + F3 ?? can you please help me?

Comment: You know $F_1=1, F_2=1, L_1=2, L_2=3$ and can work out $F_3,F_4, L_3$ from the definitions of the two sequences

Comment: So is $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$ true when $n=2$?  Is $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$ true when $n=3$?

Comment: What is unusual in this particular question is that you need two assumptions for the main step. It does not matter if you assume true for $n=k-1$ and $n=k$ and show true for $k=n+1$ or assume true for $n=k$ and $n=k+1$ and show true for $k=n+2$.

Comment: Yes$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$